# Adjectives to distinguish two meanings of "field"

Tags: field-theory, terminology, finite-fields

There are two distinct uses of the word "field".

To get this in the right basic ballpark ...

1. an abstract algebraic structure.
2. a map from space to some codomain of field values.

Because I deal with both at the same time, I frequently find some ambiguity. An electric field is an example of a vector field. Let's say a map from a manifold into a vector space. The idea here is that a field is something that is defined over all of space and time. People give Faraday the credit for coming up with the concept.

As I see the terms being used ...

A vector field is a map from a manifold to a vector space.
A real scalar field is a map from a manifold into the real numbers.
A complex scalar field is a map from a manifold into the complex numbers.

So, a matrix field should be a map from a manifold into a set of matrices. Only, what I get when I look up matrix field is an abstract algebra.

Is there some common method to clarify this with adjectives?

The class of maps from a manifold into some algebraic field is what?

A field field?

An algebraic field physical field ?

Are there any clarifying adjectives commonly used?

Comment: Usually is context that separates between meanings. For example, $\mathcal C^\infty(M)$, the algebra of smooth, real-valued functions on $M$, is not a field in the algebraic sense, but it is a space of fields in the sense of maps from $M$ to a space. For a matrix field, you can say "matrix-values vector field"

Comment: @Alessandro indeed. But the question is about situations where it can be quite ambiguous. I expect the answer will be no - no such adjectives. I have been dealing with this ever since my doctoral thesis.